# Como mostrar uma View dependendo de uma condição em SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Em meu projeto com swiftui eu gostaria de apresentar uma view dependendo do status de login dos meus usuários.

```swift
var body: some View {
    HStack() {
        HomeView()
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

`HomeView` deve aparecer se o usuário estiver logado e `LoginView` caso contrário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `@ViewBuilder` para alcançar isso:

```swift
@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
    if user.isAuthenticated {
        HomeView()
    } else {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```